# Execute stored procedure with an Output parameter?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I am trying to test. I am trying to test it through SQL Management Studio. In order to run this test I enter ...

```
exec my_stored_procedure 'param1Value', 'param2Value'
```

The final parameter is an `output parameter`. However, I do not know how to test a stored procedure with output parameters.

How do I run a stored procedure with an output parameter?

Answer (score 251, accepted):

The easy way is to right-click on the procedure in Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS), select 'Execute stored procedure..." and add values for the input parameters as prompted. SSMS will then generate the code to run the procedure in a new query window, and execute it for you. You can study the generated code to see how it is done.

Comment: I know all other possible ways to execute stored procedure(like EXEC , calling from C# or PHP) but this is the easiest and a non technical person can do this. so +1 for this and thx for sharing the information.

Comment: I don't have an `execute` command, the context menu has just a `modify`.

Comment: That seems odd. My context menu on a stored procedure has about a dozen items, including modify, execute, properties, and others

Comment: I think the answer by Jaider below completes this answer since I myself would be interested in the written command and not the mouse solution.

Comment: Another slightly different way using SSMS: right-click the SP, click "Script Stored Procedure as", then click "EXECUTE To". This will show you the TSQL.

Answer (score 211):

you can do this :

```
declare @rowCount int
exec yourStoredProcedureName @outputparameterspOf = @rowCount output
```

Answer (score 105):

Return val from procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE testme @input  VARCHAR(10),
                       @output VARCHAR(20) output
AS
  BEGIN
      IF @input >= '1'
        BEGIN
            SET @output = 'i am back';

            RETURN;
        END
  END

DECLARE @get VARCHAR(20);

EXEC testme
  '1',
  @get output

SELECT @get
```

Answer (score 57):

Check this, where the first two parameters are input parameters and the 3rd is an Output parameter in the Procedure definition.

```
DECLARE @PK_Code INT;
EXEC USP_Validate_Login 'ID', 'PWD', @PK_Code OUTPUT
SELECT @PK_Code
```

Answer (score 37):

## Procedure Example :

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[test]
@Name varchar(100),
@ID int Output   
As  
Begin   
SELECT @ID = UserID from tbl_UserMaster where  Name = @Name   
Return;
END
```

## How to call this procedure

```
Declare @ID int    
EXECUTE [dbo].[test] 'Abhishek',@ID OUTPUT   
PRINT @ID
```

Answer (score 35):

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql (originally http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499)

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE Myproc
>
> @parm varchar(10),
> **@parm1OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT**,
> **@parm2OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT**
> AS
>   SELECT @parm1OUT='parm 1' + @parm
>  SELECT @parm2OUT='parm 2' + @parm
>
> GO
>
> DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(500)
> DECLARE @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
> DECLARE @parmIN VARCHAR(10)
> DECLARE @parmRET1 VARCHAR(30)
> DECLARE @parmRET2 VARCHAR(30)
>
> SET @parmIN=' returned'
> SET @SQLString=N'EXEC Myproc @parm,
>                          @parm1OUT OUTPUT, @parm2OUT OUTPUT'
> SET @ParmDefinition=N'@parm varchar(10),
>                   @parm1OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT,
>                   @parm2OUT varchar(30) OUTPUT'
>
> EXECUTE sp_executesql
> @SQLString,
> @ParmDefinition,
> @parm=@parmIN,
> @parm1OUT=@parmRET1 OUTPUT,@parm2OUT=@parmRET2 OUTPUT
>
> SELECT @parmRET1 AS "parameter 1", @parmRET2 AS "parameter 2"
> GO
> DROP PROCEDURE Myproc
> ```

Answer (score 26):

First, declare the output variable:

```
DECLARE @MyOutputParameter INT;
```

Then, execute the stored procedure, and you can do it without parameter's names, like this:

```
EXEC my_stored_procedure 'param1Value', @MyOutputParameter OUTPUT
```

or with parameter's names:

```
EXEC my_stored_procedure @param1 = 'param1Value', @myoutput = @MyOutputParameter OUTPUT
```

And finally, you can see the output result by doing a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT @MyOutputParameter
```

Answer (score 12):

With this query you can execute any stored procedure (with or without an output parameter):

```
DECLARE @temp varchar(100)  
EXEC my_sp
    @parameter1 = 1, 
    @parameter2 = 2, 
    @parameter3 = @temp output, 
    @parameter4 = 3, 
    @parameter5 = 4
PRINT @temp
```

Here the datatype of `@temp` should be the same as `@parameter3` within your Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 10):

How about this? It's extremely simplified:

1. The SPROC below has an output parameter of `@ParentProductID`
2. We want to select the value of the output of `@ParentProductID` into `@MyParentProductID` which is declared below.
3. Here's the Code:

   ```
   declare @MyParentProductID int

   exec p_CheckSplitProduct @ProductId = 4077, @ParentProductID =  @MyParentProductID output

   select @MyParentProductID
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Try this; it's working fine for the multiple output parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [endicia].[credentialLookup]
@accountNumber varchar(20),
@login varchar(20) output,
@password varchar(50) output
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT top 1 @login = [carrierLogin],@password = [carrierPassword]
  FROM [carrier_account] where carrierLogin = @accountNumber
  order by clientId, id
END

Try for the result: 
SELECT *FROM [carrier_account] 
DECLARE @login varchar(20),@password varchar(50)
exec [endicia].[credentialLookup] '588251',@login OUTPUT,@password OUTPUT
SELECT 'login'=@login,'password'=@password
```

Answer (score 4):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE
(@PARAM1VALUE INT,
@PARAM2VALUE INT,
@OUTPARAM VARCHAR(20) OUT)
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM DBO.PARAMTABLENAME WHERE PARAM1VALUE=@PARAM1VALUE
END

DECLARE @OUTPARAM2 VARCHAR(20)
EXEC DBO.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE 1,@OUTPARAM2 OUT
PRINT @OUTPARAM2
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the stored procedure**

```
create procedure sp1
(
@id as int,
@name as nvarchar(20) out
)
as
begin
select @name=name from employee where id=@id
end
```

**And here is the way to execute the procedure**

```
 declare @name1 nvarchar(10)
    exec sp1 1,@name1 out
    print @name1
```

Answer (score 2):

**Please check below example to get output variable value by executing a stored procedure.**

```
    DECLARE @return_value int,
    @Ouput1 int,
    @Ouput2 int,
    @Ouput3 int

EXEC    @return_value = 'Your Sp Name'
        @Param1 = value1,
        @Ouput1 = @Ouput1 OUTPUT,
        @Ouput2 = @Ouput2 OUTPUT,
        @Ouput3 = @Ouput3 OUTPUT

SELECT  @Ouput1 as N'@Ouput1',
        @Ouput2 as N'@Ouput2',
        @Ouput3 as N'@Ouput3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of the stored_proc:

```
create proc product(@a int,@b int)
as
return @a * @b
```

And, this is executing it from Python:
conn = pyodbc.connect('...')
cursor = conn.cursor()

```
sql = """
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @r float
exec @r=dbo.product 5,4
select @r
"""
result = cursor.execute(sql)
print (result.fetchall())
```