# Save the Print Buffer into a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Is there any way to save the `PRINT` buffer?

Example, I have a process that runs many Stored Procedures (nested) that prints a lot of information which I need to save. The Stored Procedures are encrypted. I would like to create a Stored Procedure that calls the main SP of the process and save the `PRINT` statement results. Is it possible?

I thought of a work around: `execute master..xp_cmdshell` and `sqlcmd` with `-o`  parameter and import the output file to a table. Anybody know a better solution?

Comment: "The Stored Procedures are encrypted" - my sympathy. How did you end-up in that situation? (And you do know it's often straightforward to decrypt them, right?)

Comment: Have you considered an SQLCLR approach? The `print` output appears via the [`SqlConnection.InfoMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage) event handler as does the output from `raiserror` messages, so it's not part of the tabular rows that you can typically capture by inserting the stored procedure output into a table.

Comment: Another option is a Powershell or C# script, which can also use `SqlConnection`. You cannot capture `PRINT` messages via T-SQL

Comment: @Charlieface Just a mad thought, but can't T-SQL `OPENROWSET` connections (which use OLE-DB) capture print messages? And if so, could a `localhost`-loopback `OPENROWSET`  be used to capture print messages that way?

Comment: @Dai That's not a hack I want to even try (and it is a hack). `PRINT` messages are for debugging T-SQL, they should be used as such. They are not meant for consumption by T-SQL, it's simply the wrong tool for the job. Honestly, using `SqlConnection` is so much easier

Comment: "`PRINT` messages are for debugging T-SQL" - They have other uses: I use `RAISERROR NOWAIT` messages for passing result-set-names to clients invoking multiple-result-set procedures and batches, so my hand-written mapping methods can correctly populate multi-table datasets and object-graphs from a single sproc call.

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292273/how-can-i-capture-the-print-message-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure