# How to change data type of output of stored procedure? I want to output money data type but procedure always returns int

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

This is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spMaxOfInvoiceTotal
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @max MONEY
    SET @max = (SELECT MAX(InvoiceTotal) FROM Invoices)

    PRINT @MAX
    RETURN @MAX
END
GO
```

But when I execute, it returns int not money type.

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spMaxOfInvoiceTotal]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

As a result, a value is incorrect. It has to be `37966.19`. But procedure returns `37966.`

Even if I change `@return_value` money, I still get int. How to change procedure so return value would be money?

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedure return value is used to return exit code, it is integer.

You should define output parameter

CREATE PROCEDURE mysp
    @Maxval MONEY OUTPUT

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx

Comment: Now procedure outputs two results. 
@max 37966.16
return 37966

How to get only one result (@max 37966.16)?

Comment: @Timur, you can just do return and select out variable alone, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589466/execute-stored-procedure-with-an-output-parameter

Comment: @Timur, were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What RDBMS is this for? **SQL Server**?

The value **returned** from a stored procedure in SQL Server is **always** `INT` and you can't change that - it's typically used to convey back a success/failure flag, or a "number of rows affected" information.

If you to "return" a `MONEY` (or better yet: `DECIMAL`) value - you can either use an `OUTPUT` parameter (which works fine for a single value), or you need to return a *result set* with that value.

So in your case, you could try something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMaxOfInvoiceTotal
    @MaxValue DECIMAL(20,4) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET @MaxValue = (SELECT MAX(InvoiceTotal) FROM Invoices)
END
GO
```

and then call this stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @RC INT
DECLARE @MaxValue DECIMAL(20,4)

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[GetMaxOfInvoiceTotal] @MaxValue OUTPUT
GO
```