# How to correct the scalar variable declaration error in my SQL job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, sp-send-dbmail

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have the following stored procedure which is returning the required output in the form of a HTML table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ITB_SendEmail
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Body2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TableHead VARCHAR(1000),
        @TableTail VARCHAR(1000)

SET @TableTail = '</table></body></html>' ;
SET @TableHead = '<html><head>' + '<style>'
    + 'td {border: solid black;border-width: 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font: 11px arial} '
    + '</style>' + '</head>' + '<body>' + 'Report generated on : '
    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 106) 
    + ' <br> <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' 
    + '<tr> <td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>StayYear</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Market</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jan</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Feb</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Mar</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Apr</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>May</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jun</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Jul</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Aug</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Sep</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Oct</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Nov</b></td>'
    + '<td bgcolor=#E6E6FA><b>Dec</b></td>';

SET @Body = ( SELECT td = StayYear, '',
                        td = Market, '',
                        td = Jan, '',
                        td = Feb, '',
                        td = Mar, '',
                        td = Apr, '',
                        td = May, '',
                        td = Jun, '',
                        td = Jul, '',
                        td = Aug, '',
                        td = Sep, '',
                        td = Oct, '',
                        td = Nov, '',
                        td = Dec, ''
              FROM  View1               
                FOR   XML RAW('tr'),
                      ELEMENTS
            )


SET  @Body2 = @TableHead + ISNULL(@Body, '') + @TableTail

SELECT  @Body2

END
```

I have now set up a SQL job which is supposed to execute this stored procedure and emails the output to a recipient. My SQL Server job runs a T-SQL query (see below):

```
DECLARE @GeneratedHTML NVARCHAR(MAX); 
EXEC ITB_SendEmail @GeneratedHTML = @Body2 OUTPUT

EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='BI',
  @copy_recipients ='',
  @recipients='xxx@yyyy.com',
  @subject='ITB',
  @body= @GeneratedHTML ,
  @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

However, the SQL Server job is failing with the following an error message:

> Must declare the scalar variable @Body2. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 137). The step failed

I cannot figure out the scalar variable declaration issue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JohnWoo It is there.

Comment: @user3115933 no, it's not. We're talking about the second statement, not the first.

Comment: @TabAlleman It is declared in my stored procedure.

Comment: The stored procedure must itself declare `@Body2` explicitly as an output parameter. You can't just pluck out arbitrary variables inside the body from the call site.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks but I lost you here. Can you help on how to re-write that part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute stored procedure with an Output parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589466/execute-stored-procedure-with-an-output-parameter)

Comment: I recommend consulting the [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql#f-using-output-parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not referring to the variable in your Stored Procedure code if that's what you're thinking.

It's saying you need to DECLARE `@Body2` in your Execution Batch.  However you have more problems than that.   You are trying to access an output parameter of your stored procedure, but in your stored procedure you haven't got an output parameter.

Reading the [documentation on Output parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) would be a good start.

Assuming you correctly set `@Body2` as an output parameter in your stored procedure, then you simply need to reverse their order in the execution statement:

```
DECLARE @GeneratedHTML NVARCHAR(MAX); 

EXEC ITB_SendEmail  @Body2 = @GeneratedHTML  OUTPUT

EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='BI',
  @copy_recipients ='',
  @recipients='xxx@yyyy.com',
  @subject='ITB',
  @body= @GeneratedHTML ,
  @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Comment: I tried your solution and I am now getting the following error from the SQL job: "Procedure ITB_SendEmail has no parameters and arguments were supplied."Any ideas where to look for the cause/s of the error?

Comment: Sounds like you did not set up the output parameter correctly in the first stored procedure.   Edit your question and post the new code.

Comment: I did not edit the Stored Procedure. I went through the link you provided regarding output parameters but I am still a little confused on how to implement it in my scenario.

Comment: What part of it is confusing you?   The link provides sample code for how to edit your stored procedure.   You need to make `@Body2` an OUTPUT parameter in your stored procedure, and not a local variable the way you have it now.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into that again and report back.

Comment: Thanks for all your support. Worked out perfectly!