# Set Output parameter to rowcount

Tags: sql-server

I have the following procedure

```
create procedure hozzaszolas
  @pHozzaszolasSzam int
  , @pmcsz int output
as
begin
  update Cikkek
    set Ertekeles = Ertekeles + 1
  where Cikkek.CikkCim in (
    select Cikkek.CikkCim
    from Cikkek
    left join Hozzaszolasok on Cikkek.CikkID = Hozzaszolasok.CikkID
    where Cikkek.Ertekeles < 10
    group by Cikkek.CikkID, Cikkek.CikkCim
    having count(Hozzaszolasok.CikkID) >= @pHozzaszolasSzam
  )
end
```

I would like to get the number of rows affected in the output param, but I don't know how.

Comment: `set @pmcsz=@@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: how to execute the 'hozzaszolas' procedure?

Comment: Did you google that before asking? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589466/execute-stored-procedure-with-an-output-parameter

Comment: thanks for the answers, it works now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute stored procedure with an Output parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589466/execute-stored-procedure-with-an-output-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

[`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns the number of records affected by the last statement.

```
create procedure hozzaszolas
  @pHozzaszolasSzam int
  , @pmcsz int output
as
begin
  update Cikkek
    set Ertekeles = Ertekeles + 1
  where Cikkek.CikkCim in (
    select Cikkek.CikkCim
    from Cikkek
    left join Hozzaszolasok on Cikkek.CikkID = Hozzaszolasok.CikkID
    where Cikkek.Ertekeles < 10
    group by Cikkek.CikkID, Cikkek.CikkCim
    having count(Hozzaszolasok.CikkID) >= @pHozzaszolasSzam
  )
set @pmcsz= @@ROWCOUNT
end
```